# ggbump::geom_bump 'StatBump' needs at least two observations per group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a plot with ggbump where I have different variables on the horizontal axis and rank on the vertical axis.

This is how the data looks like:

```
> head(data)
  country                                 names rank
1      ar                       Masa\n promedio    1
2      ar                          Masa\n total    1
3      ar Cantidad\n promedio de\n instrumentos    1
4      ar    Cantidad\n total de\n instrumentos    1
5      ar    Cantidad\n de satélites\n lanzados    1
6      br                       Masa\n promedio    2
```

However, my "variables" (the ones I want on the horizontal axis, not in my dataframe) are characters (more precisely: "Masa promedio", "Masa total", "Cantidad promedio de instrumentos", "Cantidad total de instrumentos", "Cantidad de satélites lanzados"), so when I render the plot, I get the warning `In compute_group(...) : 'StatBump' needs at least two observations per group`. If instead of using the variable names I mentioned above I use "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" (not as characters), I get the type of plot I want (see below), but not the variable names I want on the x-axis.

In conclusion, how can I make the following plot but instead of saying "1", "2", ... in the x-axis, say "Masa promedio", "Masa total", "Cantidad promedio de instrumentos", "Cantidad total de instrumentos", "Cantidad de satélites lanzados"?. Code is also below (ommited some irrelevant parts):

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(
  country = c(rep("ar", 5),
              rep("br", 5),
              rep("cl", 5),
              rep("co", 5),
              rep("cr", 5),
              rep("ec", 5),
              rep("gt", 5),
              rep("mx", 5),
              rep("py", 5),
              rep("pe", 5),
              rep("uy", 5)),
  names = c(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 11)),
  rank = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
           2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
           5, 3, 5, 3, 4,
           6, 8, 7, 8, 7,
           9, 9, 10, 9, 8,
           8, 6, 6, 6, 5,
           10, 11, 11, 11, 9,
           4, 4, 3, 4, 3,
           3, 4, 4, 10, 10,
           11, 5, 8, 5, 6,
           7, 7, 9, 7, 11)
)

ggplot(data, aes(names, rank, country = country, color = country)) +
  geom_bump(size = 0.25, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_flag(size = 7) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(color = "none") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 1:11)
```

Note that if I replace `names = c(rep(c("Masa\n promedio", "Masa\n total", "Cantidad\n promedio de\n instrumentos", "Cantidad\n total de\n instrumentos", "Cantidad\n de satélites\n lanzados"), 11))` where it says `names = c(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 11)),`  I would get the warnings and not the correct plot displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mapping the `names` directly on `x` the issue is that you have to explicitly set the `group` aesthetic as you are mapping a discrete variable on `x`. A more or less a general rule for line plots as is the case with `geom_bump`.

In case you want to stick with the numerical values you could set the axis labels via the `labels` argument of `scale_x_continuous`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbump)
library(ggflags)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

labels <- setNames(c(
  "Masa\n promedio", "Masa\n total",
  "Cantidad\n promedio de\n instrumentos",
  "Cantidad\n total de\n instrumentos", "Cantidad\n de satélites\n lanzados"
), 1:5)

ggplot(data, aes(names, rank, country = country, color = country)) +
  geom_bump(size = 0.25, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_flag(size = 7) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, labels = labels) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(color = "none") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 1:11)
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was
#> generated.
```

[image]

Or you map the names or labels directly on `x` but in that case add `group=country` to the aesthetics:

```r
data$names <- c(rep(c(
  "Masa\n promedio", "Masa\n total",
  "Cantidad\n promedio de\n instrumentos",
  "Cantidad\n total de\n instrumentos", "Cantidad\n de satélites\n lanzados"
), 11))

ggplot(data, aes(names, rank, country = country, color = country, group = country)) +
  geom_bump(size = 0.25, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_flag(size = 7) +
  theme_minimal() +
  guides(color = "none") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 1:11)
```

[image]